# Saving a screenshot cocos2d-x android

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

```
void SaveScreenshot()   
{
   CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
   CCRenderTexture* texture = CCRenderTexture::create((int)size.width, (int)size.height);    
   texture->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));    
   texture->begin();
   CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit();
   texture->end();
   texture->saveToFile("screenshot.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
}
```

How can I access the screenshot with native java on android?
I want to create a chooser for a send intent, but I can't seem to find the directory that cocos2dx `saveToFile()` writes to.. help?

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: set a breakpoint, then step into the save method

Comment: @SumitKandoi What is the directory that saveToFile() writes to?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Is there no easier way, like simply locating the directory saveToFile() writes to?

Comment: Don't know, it's what I would do if I needed to find out. I don't know if there's a standard directory or what it would be on Android and with cocos2d-x and screenshot saving specifically, but it should be right there in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call java method that will create  your screenshot image.

```
    public static void ScreenShot()
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Cocos2dxHelper.getCocos2dxWritablePath() + "/" + "screenshot.png");

        String fileHolder = "SampleFolder";
        File filepathData = new File("/sdcard/" + fileHolder);

        //~~~Create Dir
        try {
                if (!filepathData.exists()) 
                {
                    filepathData.mkdirs();
                    filepathData.createNewFile();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepathData + fileHolder);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    String toSave = String.valueOf(0);
                    out.write(toSave);
                    out.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) {

            }   

            //~~~Create Image
            File file = new File("/sdcard/" + "Your filename");

            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {}

            Uri phototUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
            //~~~Add Code Below
    }
```

Comment: This looked promising but filepathData is a read-only file system `java.io.IOException: Read-only file system`

Comment: @GameDevGuru sd card wripe permission is there?